# Efficient way of simultaneously deriving count of unique values and summary values for grouped values in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, dplyr, group-summaries

I'm interested in finding an efficient manner to obtain a *summary by group* table that would contain:

- Count for unique values per group
- A primitive set of descriptive statistics for selected variables

For example, in case of generating the descriptive statistics I'm using the code below:

```
data("mtcars")
require(dplyr)
mt_sum <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(min,max), hp, wt, disp)
```

which would generate the desired output:

```
> head(mt_sum)

Source: local data frame [3 x 7]

    cyl hp_min wt_min disp_min hp_max wt_max disp_max
  (dbl)  (dbl)  (dbl)    (dbl)  (dbl)  (dbl)    (dbl)
1     4     52  1.513     71.1    113  3.190    146.7
2     6    105  2.620    145.0    175  3.460    258.0
3     8    150  3.170    275.8    335  5.424    472.0
```

I'm interested in enriching the data with figure that would reflect count of values per each group. With respect to the count, this can be simply done:

```
mt_sum2 <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(countObs = n())
```

which would generate the required data:

```
> head(mt_sum2)
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

    cyl countObs
  (dbl)    (int)
1     4       11
2     6        7
3     8       14
```

## Problem

The problem occurs when I would like to simultaneously apply both transformations.

### Attempt 1

For example the code:

```
mt_sum <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(min,max), hp, wt, disp) %>% 
  summarise(countObs = n())
```

would generate:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

    cyl countObs
  (dbl)    (int)
1     4       11
2     6        7
3     8       14
```

without the descriptive statistics that were previously generated.

### Attempt 2

The code:

```
mt_sum <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(min,max,n), hp, wt, disp)
```

will expectedly fail:

> `Error: n does not take arguments`

### Attempt 3 (working)

The code:

```
data("mtcars")
require(dplyr)
mt_sum <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(min,max), hp, wt, disp) %>% 
  left_join(y = data.frame(
    "Var1" = as.numeric(as.character(as.data.frame(table(mtcars$cyl))$Var1)),
    "Count" = as.character(as.data.frame(table(mtcars$cyl))$Freq)),
            by = c("cyl" = "Var1"))
```

will deliver the required data:

```
> head(mt_sum)
Source: local data frame [3 x 8]

    cyl hp_min wt_min disp_min hp_max wt_max disp_max  Count
  (dbl)  (dbl)  (dbl)    (dbl)  (dbl)  (dbl)    (dbl) (fctr)
1     4     52  1.513     71.1    113  3.190    146.7     11
2     6    105  2.620    145.0    175  3.460    258.0      7
3     8    150  3.170    275.8    335  5.424    472.0     14
```

---

I think this is extremely inefficient way of producing this summary. In particular, creating objects *on the fly* is inefficient when working with big tables. I'm interested in achieving the same results but in a more efficient manner that would not involve creating objects just for the purpose of merging. In particular, what I would like to do in `dplyr` would correspond to deriving additional summaries from the previous version of the table. For example:

1. Group
2. Produce descriptive statistics
3. Come back to the data after **group**
4. Produce some additional statistics and add to the final data

Comment: `summarise_each(funs(min,max,length), hp, wt, disp)` ?

Comment: @jeremycg Thanks for showing the interest. I was thinking of something on those lines `hp_length wt_length disp_length`, I would have to remove those columns via `select`. I don't find the `select` syntax easiest to mange, it would have to correspond to *keep only one column with `length` and drop rest but keep all previous columns for other summaries* or something like that.

Comment: you could use `select(-grep("length", names(.))[-1])`. The timing is about the same as the left_join answer below - it will depend on the size and scale of your data

Comment: @jeremycg Thanks very much for this, it's a neat solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another (shorter) option using a `left_join`:

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>%  
    summarise_each(funs(min,max), hp, wt, disp) %>% 
    left_join(count(mtcars, cyl))
#Joining by: "cyl"
#Source: local data frame [3 x 8]
#
#    cyl hp_min wt_min disp_min hp_max wt_max disp_max     n
#  (dbl)  (dbl)  (dbl)    (dbl)  (dbl)  (dbl)    (dbl) (int)
#1     4     52  1.513     71.1    113  3.190    146.7    11
#2     6    105  2.620    145.0    175  3.460    258.0     7
#3     8    150  3.170    275.8    335  5.424    472.0    14
```